# Trouble compiling sphinxtrain in visual studio

Tags: cmusphinx

I have successfully build sphinxbase. When I tried compiling sphinxtrain, it says 
"The program can't start because sphinxbase.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program"

I checked sphinxtrain/bin/release and saw that I have sphinxbase.dll in that folder. What could be the problem?

This is whats showing in the output window

```
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Sphinx\SphinxTrain\bin\Debug\agg_seg.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Sphinx\SphinxTrain\bin\Debug\sphinxbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'agg_seg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[6444] agg_seg.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run binary from Debug folder, you need to copy debug version of sphinxbase.dll from sphinxbase build `sphinxbase/bin/Debug` to that `sphinxtrain/bin/Debug` folder. dll must be in the current folder.